# How to fix "Requiring unknown module "573"." in react-native?

Tags: react-native, runtime-error

Requiring unknown module "573".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro Bundler. You may also want to run `yarn`, or `npm install` (depending on your environment).
loadModuleImplementation
    B:\reactNative\RamadanApp\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:280:29

    B:\reactNative\RamadanApp\index.js:6
loadModuleImplementation
    B:\reactNative\RamadanApp\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:331:6
guardedLoadModule
    B:\reactNative\RamadanApp\node_modules\metro\src\lib\polyfills\require.js:197:45
global code

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following commands:

```
npm install
npm audit fix
```

And restarted the Metro Bundler.